# Properties from inherited classes not binding as expected in WPF

Tags: c#

I am binding a list of objects to a listbox control in WPF and the properties of the inherited base class of the objects are not binding.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public string MyProp
}
public class MyClass:BaseClass
{
}
```

When binding list it acts as though MyProp is not a valid properity, even if I use a .convertall(t => t as BaseClass)

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error`

What am I missing?

Comment: MyProp is not property ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF databinding to a Size property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743992/wpf-databinding-to-a-size-property)

Comment: correction, field, but why shout it behave any differently?

Comment: @YohDeadfall How is that a duplicate?

Comment: Because you have the same problem. In WPF bindings does not support fileds.

Comment: @Wobbles Because WPF can only bind to CLR properties or dependency properties.  It can't bind to fields.

Comment: When creating a field arn't get and set assumed? just as the field is assumed when defining a property by {get;set;}?

Comment: @Wobbles Fields don't have getters and setters, they're just variables attached to an instance.  That's what differentiates them from properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a `Binding` in WPF you must have a `Property` on your view-model to bind to. In the code you have provided you are using a `Field`. The following is an example of a `Binding` on a property.

```
public class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string MyProp
    {
        get
        {
           return mMyProp;
        }
        set
        {
           if( Equals( mMyProp, value ) ) return;
           mMyProp = value;

           OnPropertyChanged( "MyProp" );
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );  
    }

    //  The field.
    private string mMyProp;
}
```

I should note that the `INotifyPropertChanged` interface and implementation is not required. It is required if you are expecting changes to the property to be reflected on your UI.

And your derived class:

```
public MyClass : BaseClass
{
    //  ...
}
```

And your binding in XAML assuming your `DataContext` is that of `MyClass`:

```
<!-- .. -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProp}"/>
<!-- .. -->
```